# Export named arrow function got "Object(...) is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In a React app I wrote a function in `file1.js` and use this function in `file2.js`

```
// file1.js
export const withPrefix = (Component) => (props) => (
  <PrefixContext.Consumer>
    {prefix => <Component {...props} prefix={prefix}/>}
  </PrefixContext.Consumer>
)

// file2.js
import { withPrefix } from '/path/to/file1.js'
let Toolbar = withPrefix(({prefix}) => ( // !error happens here
  <Fragment>
    <div style={{flexGrow: 1}}>
      <Button><Link to={`${prefix}/create`}>New Artifact</Link></Button>
    </div>
    <Search style={{width: 200}}/>
  </Fragment>
))
```

Then I got the error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function". So I changed export `withPrefix` function

```
export function withPrefix(Component) {
  return (props) => (
    <PrefixContext.Consumer>
      {prefix => <Component {...props} prefix={prefix}/>}
    </PrefixContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

And the error is gone, everything works. But I wonder why these two exports result differently?
And another question is if I want to export an arrow function in es6, is the 2nd `export function` style the only method?

**Attachment 1** (DefaultView.js):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Layout} from 'antd'

import Toolbar from './Toolbar'
import Content from './Content'

export const PrefixContext = React.createContext()

export function withPrefix(Component) {
  return (props) => (
    <PrefixContext.Consumer>
      {prefix => <Component {...props} prefix={prefix}/>}
    </PrefixContext.Consumer>
  )
}

export default class DefaultView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      view: props.defaultView
    }
  }

  handleViewChange = (view) => {
    this.setState({view})
  }

  render() {
    const {prefix, views} = this.props
    const {view} = this.state
    return (
      <PrefixContext.Provider value={prefix}>
        <Layout>
          <Toolbar view={view} views={views} onViewChange= 
   {this.handleViewChange}/>
          <hr/>
          <Content view={view}/>
        </Layout>
      </PrefixContext.Provider>
    )
  }

}
```

**Attachment 2** (Summary.js)

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react'
import {Button, Input} from 'antd'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import ArtifactTable from './ArtifactTable'
import {withPrefix} from "./DefaultView"

const {Search} = Input

export const Toolbar = withPrefix(({prefix}) => (
  <Fragment>
    <div style={{flexGrow: 1}}>
      <Button><Link to={`${prefix}/create`}>新建软件包</Link></Button>
    </div>
    <Search style={{width: 200}}/>
  </Fragment>
))

class Summary extends Component {

  state = {
    data: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {prefix} = this.props
    console.log('prefix=' + prefix)
    fetch(prefix).then(json => {
      this.setState({data: json.content})
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {data} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <ArtifactTable data={data}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default withPrefix(Summary)
```

**Attachment 3** (Toolbar.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import {Toolbar as SummaryToolbar} from './Summary'
import Create from './Create'
import Details from './Details'
import Edit from './Edit'

import {withPrefix} from "./DefaultView"

const Toolbar = withPrefix(({prefix, view, onViewChange}) => (
  <div style={{background: '#fff', padding: 16, display: 'flex', 
alignItems: 'baseline'}}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${prefix}`} component={SummaryToolbar}/>
      <Route exact path={`${prefix}/create`}
         component={() => <Create.Toolbar view={view} onViewChange= 
   {onViewChange}/>}/>
      <Route exact path={`${prefix}/:id`}
             component={() => <Details.Toolbar view={view} onViewChange= 
   {onViewChange}/>}/>
      <Route exact path={`${prefix}/:id/edit`}
             component={() => <Edit.Toolbar view={view} onViewChange= 
   {onViewChange}/>}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
))

export default Toolbar
```

**Update** It's indeed the cyclic dependency problem as @Bergi and @loganfsmyth said. After I moved out 
 the `withPrefix` export snippet into a new file `Context.js` from `DefaultView.js`, the problem resolved. But I still have one quesion. In a cyclic dependency circumstances, why `export const f = () => () => {}` different from `export function f() => { return () => {} }`. Is `export const` lazy evaluated than `export function` as @loganfsmyth said?

Comment: So If I want to export a thunk function in es6. The 2nd export is the only method? @Noface

Comment: There's no `import` declaration in your `file2.js`?! Please post the whole code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any chance there are circular dependencies involved? There, using a proper declaration would make a difference.

Comment: I leave out that part for concise @Bergi and I re-edit my question

Comment: `export const ...` should work just fine. Could you show a complete example on how you're using `withPrefix` (what's going on inside the Fragments)?

Comment: updated the question @SrThompson

Comment: `
export const withPrefix = (Component) =>{
 return (props) => (
  <PrefixContext.Consumer>
    {prefix => <Component {...props} prefix={prefix}/>}
  </PrefixContext.Consumer>
)
}
`
this should also work

Comment: @SyamPillai I test it. It does not work and the error is the same

Comment: @bitweaver and how are you using `Toolbar`? side note: there is no reason why these exports should do different things... they're essentially equivalent

Comment: @SrThompson Updated again

Comment: @Bergi is correct, you have a dependency cycle. `export const withPrefix` hasn't executed yet when you get your error, so you just get an `undefined` value.